# How to get out off bootloop?

Tags: boot-loop

Can you tell me how to get past bootloop on my HTC desire 620g dual sim. I did an software update, but it failed. Help please

Comment: Add more information please.  Was the update that you tried to install an official one from the manufacturer? How and where did you obtain this update (automatic download, manual download from some site, etc.)? Is your phone running stock firmware, or a custom ROM? When you say "it failed" what exactly do you mean? Were there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to get to recovery mode, maybe you can flash a stock rom or use a backup. You may also be able to use ADB to flash a working rom, [this tutorial](http://htc-one.gadgethacks.com/how-to/fix-soft-bricked-htc-one-by-flashing-new-rom-via-adb-0154361/) is for the htc one but it's mostly the same.

You can also just keep turning it on I guess, I've gotten lucky plenty of times when a phone that was seemingly bricked and not exiting a bootloop just decided to work one day.

Also, if you are having issues flashing roms to your phone you should probably do a bit more research. Using reliable cables, not turning off devices and doing a bit of research into other people who were able to successfully flash and those who unsuccessfully flashed to a device is always a good way to prevent these mishaps as well as fix them. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJRzTLvDKz8) explains the process quite well.